# pgfortran equivalent of -J switch in gfortran

Tags: gfortran, pgi

When I compile code in gfortran I can use the `-J/dir/` switch to set an output directory for .mod files.
Now I'm switching to compile with the PGI pgfortran compiler but can't find the equivalent.

What is the pgfortran equivalent of `-J`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the PGI compiler (and Intel's) the `-module` option is the one you want.  This isn't entirely obvious, depending on which documentation you read.

From `pgf90 -help`:

> -module <dir>       Add search directory for module information files

but from the reference manual

> -module <moduledir> (F90/F95 only) Save/search for module files in directory <moduledir>

So, `-module` both saves generated module files to the chosen directory and adds that directory to the search path.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.